# What were typical problems during developing on ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, user-experience

What were typical problems during developing on ASP.NET? So, would  you like  to describe typical problems/mistakes during developing on ASP.NET from your experience?

**UPD**
I have been working as ASP.NET developer for 2 monthes.

Comment: Survey type questions (like this) should be Community Wiki.

Comment: Also, difficult for me to describe "typical" problems, all I can tell you are the problems I've encountered. I don't know if they're typical or atypical.

Comment: @ Binary Worrier , so If you have time and desire, please describe it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say ASP.NET I'm assuming you mean WebForms.

The biggest problems are related to DataBinding, event handling, viewstate and control id's. These concepts are entangled in complex ways that start to break down whenever you take even a single step outside the beaten paths.

WebForms was built to provide a similar experience to web development as to desktop UI development. After years of ASP.NET WebForms development experience I think I can safely say that WinForms does not live up to the promise. The attempt to hide web specific concepts (like the fact that HTTP is stateless) means that you as developer loose a lot of control, which makes it hard to figure out what the problem is when something does not work as you'd expect.

For anyone starting .NET-based web development I suggest you get intimate with more modern web development platforms like the ASP.NET MVC or MonoRail. The initial learning curve may be a bit steeper but when you get rolling you'll be much more productive.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest mistake in my opinion is that many people do not take the time to learn and understand the framework before they begin coding. This often leads to solutions that do not follow the intentions/paradigm of the framework.

Answer (score 3):

My biggest issue was the page lifecycle.  When you start adding Masterpages & user controls, it gets a bit tricker figuring out what happens and in what order

Answer (score 2):

Most of the asp.net web forms problem has been overcome by asp.net mvc framework. The problem in web forms were many. The biggest i feel is it has only one form. others are misuse of viewstate, which later overcome by control state. Web form has complex page life cycle specially if you are dynamically adding user controls etc.

On the other hand i see no problem in asp.net mvc framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think most common mistakes on developing not only in Asp.net is that when you try to study something or just a part of it and feel like you need to stop because you think you know everything which is obviously wrong. For me Asp.net is like the world because when you know the continent of Asia,Europe,etc. it doesn't mean that you need to stop because you already know a lot of things. I think it's not that way because Asp.net have so many capabilities that every developer can explore like me who is also still studying and when you learn something, like me most of the time I say hey I never thought this exist in the map of Asp.net and again I say hey you know what I learn something new, I wonder if my previous project applies to what I learn today. Things like that, I learn in every step and the ladder never ends.

Answer (score 1):

I think making a statement about your background/experience and knowledge of Http, Html etc. might help people give a better, more meaningful response.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view,the biggest problem in considered to the state management.
The people often get confused what to use on a particular situation.

Next one is most of don't know about the page life cycle well.which is most important during custom controls and all.

And the most important thing is new comers often don't know how to actually indulge oops concepts while software development..

Answer (score 0):

Typical problem #1: Master pages. Coming from classic ASP, this concept was new to me so I learned how to use it properly in "the hard way". In the beginning I tried to change things defined in the master page from within content pages which is obviously wrong.

Typical problem #2: User Controls. The classic ASP does have "include" mechanism allowing the programmer to put repetitive blocks of code so I was familiar with the basic concept, but combining it with existing Page, learning the different life cycle and understanding the real power of the custom controls took long time and many bumps on the road.